# React functional components, setState and immutability

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Feeling a little dumb, I've been working with React for 2 years and always thought that you have to use `setState` with a new copy of the object to avoid mutating the state. However, this example mutates the state and uses `setState` with the same object reference without any issue.

Why does this work?

[Working Code Pen](https://codepen.io/gfels/pen/rNGqvpX?editors=1111)

```
const { useState } = React;

const Counter = () => {
  const [countObject, setCountObject] = useState({count: 0});

  const onClick = () => {
    countObject.count = countObject.count + 1;
    setCountObject(countObject); // mutated object, same reference
    
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {countObject.count} times</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

Comment: Interestingly, I can't reproduce this behaviour in Stack snippets (Stack overflow's snippet editor). I'm guessing something's up with codepen?

Comment: Actually, it's an issue with your react version: check your `umd` links that you're using in your codepen, they are alpha versions (16.7.0-alpha.2), probably some bug in that. Try with `17.0.2` instead of `16.7.0-alpha.2`

Comment: Thanks, @NickParsons, this was the issue! :) Forked codepen, didn't notice the original author used alpha versions.

Comment: @gfels great :) glad it's resolved now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your codepen is using an alpha version of React 16.7. Hooks were released in 16.8, so to use hooks reliably, you should be using a version 16.8 or above (in a non-alpha version of React):

[image]

You can update the version number of both of the above links by clicking the gear icon in your codepen on the JavaScript pane.

Notice the below snippet uses **16.7.0-alpha.2** and has the same issue you were experiencing:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Counter = () => {
  const [countObject, setCountObject] = useState({count: 0});

  const onClick = () => {
    countObject.count = countObject.count + 1;
    setCountObject(countObject);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {countObject.count} times</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

However, changing your version to **16.8** or later fixes the issue (as of writing this, we're up to v17.0.2):

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Counter = () => {
  const [countObject, setCountObject] = useState({count: 0});

  const onClick = () => {
    countObject.count = countObject.count + 1;
    setCountObject(countObject);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {countObject.count} times</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: As an aside and purely to answer the implied question of why this no longer works in the current version of React: In the react reconciler in the new hooks implementation, in the rerenderReducer on line 947 we can see that there's some code to register an update was received that checks whether the latest value matches the previously memoized value. Internally this uses `Object.is` when available.

`if (!is(newState, hook.memoizedState)) { markWorkInProgressReceivedUpdate();}`

Comment: Source 1 - React codebase line 947: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/811634762a389bce81bdc145f84bdf247910b8dd/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.new.js#L947

Comment: Source 2 - MDN Object.is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/is

Comment: @JamieDixon Oh interesting, thanks for that further insight on that. That's great to see how the react internals handle this "under the hood".

Answer (score 0):

Immutability is very important of course, your code works, just because modify the original object doestn't affect functions. Change the code by sharing initial value, then click arbitary button, you will find something wrong.

```
const { useState } = React;

const Counter = () => {
  const value = { count: 0 }
  const [countObject, setCountObject] = useState(value);
  const [countObject2, setCountObject2] = useState(value);

  const onClick = () => {
    countObject.count = countObject.count + 1;
    setCountObject(countObject);
  }
  
  const onClick2 = () => {
    countObject2.count = countObject2.count + 1;
    setCountObject(countObject2);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {countObject.count} times</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>
        Click me
      </button>

      <p>You2 clicked {countObject2.count} times</p>
      <button onClick={onClick2}>
        Click me2
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<div><Counter /></div>, document.getElementById('app'))
```